# ViewPager shows views on top of each other

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to implement a ViewPager, but currently it renders all the views on one screen, and when moving to the next it is empty it contains all the content. I have a feeling it has to do with the Fragment within Fragment or so, but I cannot figure it out.

In the screenshot below you can kind of see it:

[image]

This is (part) of the code. (ArticlePagerAdapter is just an implementation of the proto to look up that specific object type).

```
public abstract class PrototypePagerActivity<T extends GenericModel> extends BaseActivity {

    PrototypePagerAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_proto_pager);

        long categoryId = -1;
        int articlePos = 0;

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            //if (extras.containsKey("articleId")) articleId = extras.getInt("articleId");
            if (extras.containsKey("position")) articlePos = extras.getInt("position");
            if (extras.containsKey("categoryId")) categoryId = extras.getLong("categoryId");
        }
        mAdapter = new ArticlePagerAdapter(categoryId,getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.protoPager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mPager.setCurrentItem(articlePos);
    }

}

public abstract class PrototypePagerAdapter<T extends GenericModel> extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        try {
            T object = getObjectForPosition(position);

            ArticleFragment articleFragment = new ArticleFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putLong("articleId", object.getId());
            articleFragment.setArguments(args);
            return articleFragment;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w(iDomsAndroidApp.TAG, "Problem getting the object instance for pages", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public abstract T getObjectForPosition(int position) throws Exception;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return requestObjectCount();
    }

    public abstract int requestObjectCount();

}

public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {   
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_article, container, false);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content_fragment, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        ArticleHeaderFragment articleHeaderFragment = new ArticleHeaderFragment();
        articleHeaderFragment.setArguments(getArguments());
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.header_fragment, articleHeaderFragment).commit();

        ArticleContentFragment articleContentFragment = ArticleContentFragment.newInstance();
        articleContentFragment.setArguments(getArguments());
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_fragment, articleContentFragment).commit();

        return view;
    }    
}
```

activity_proto_pager.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/protoPager" />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_article.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/background_image"
        android:alpha="0.6" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/audio_control_fragment" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/header_fragment" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/content_fragment" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_article_header.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/list_background_overlay"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    tools:context="org.idoms.iDomsAndroid.fragments.ArticleHeaderFragment">

    <org.idoms.iDomsAndroid.views.ResizableImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/article_imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the fragment. Relevant snippets  maybe, not the whole thing

Comment: you have only one `Fragment` `ArticleFragment` in adapter, so ...

Comment: I added the ArticleFragment code and cleaned up some unnecessary items.

Comment: Instead of adding new fragment in savedInstanceState try replace

Comment: @Xcihnegn could you elaborate? The relevant adapter functions (count and  getItem() are called and do return the proper items).

Comment: @penguin does that mean just taking out the savedInstanceState and put null in?

Comment: no instead of ".add(...)" use ".replace(....)"

Comment: @penguin now they don't overlap anymore, but items are still viewd on that one screen (and when swapping that first view is updated)

Comment: Try `getChildFragmentManager()` to replace `getFragmentManager()` inside your `ArticleFragment`, then should work

Comment: @Xcihnegn getChildFragmentManager() to replace getFragmentManager() did the job!

Answer (score 0):

You should replace fragment instead of add.

So, instead of `.add(...)` use `.replace(....)`

**Update:**

You are adding fragment at two more places. Do above step with `articleHeaderFragment` and `articleContentFragment`. You can add second part of code in else part (If it is according to your logic)

**Update 2**

You should revisit your logic as well. Like in the code, below, you are adding two fragment in `R.id.content_fragment`. Replace can help here, but your code will be redundant

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .add(R.id.content_fragment, new PlaceholderFragment())
     .commit();
}

ArticleContentFragment articleContentFragment = ArticleContentFragment.newInstance();
articleContentFragment.setArguments(getArguments());
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_fragment, articleContentFragment).commit();
```